# Laravel - Unique validation of country update not working

Tags: laravel

I have a code in Laravel-8, I am trying to use Request Rules for the validation:

Request Rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'country_name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:2',
            'max:100',
            Rule::unique('countries', 'name')->ignore($this->country)
        ],
    ];
}
```

route:

```
| POST | api/v1/core/updateCountry  | core.country.update | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Core\CountryController@updateCountry | api
```

The table name is countries.

What is the best way to validate the unique in update for country name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ignore method needs the primary key of the country you're ignoring. I guess you're sending it in the request (for update purposes)

```
Rule::unique('countries', 'name')->ignore($this->id)
```

Comment: @N695 - country id is id